# Google Sign In One Tap & Laravel Socialite - Bad Request 400: Missing required parameter: code

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set up Google Sign In One Tap in my website and I just dont know what else to try. I just dosent work. Always the same error.

> Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
   data-client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   data-context="signin"
   data-ux_mode="popup"
   data-login_uri="http://localhost/auth/google/callback"
   data-auto_select="false"
   data-_token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</div>
```

LARAVEL CONTROLLER

```
   public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();
    }


    public function callback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
            $finduser = User::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();

            if ($finduser) {
                Auth::login($finduser);
                return redirect('/');

            } else {
                $find_email = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();

                if ($find_email) {
                    return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['msg', 'That email address is already registered.']);
                } else {

                    $newUser = new User();
                    $newUser->name = $user->name;
                    $newUser->email = $user->email;
                    $newUser->google_id = $user->google_id;
                    $newUser->save();
                    try {
                        Mail::to($newUser)->queue(new NewAccount());
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {

                    }
                }
                Auth::login($newUser);
                return redirect('/');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['msg', $e->getMessage()]);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['msg', $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

DEPENDECIES

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4",
    "intervention/image": "^2.7",
    "invisnik/laravel-steam-auth": "^4.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/socialite": "^5.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.3",
    "spatie/laravel-backup": "^7.0"
},
```

It always fails in this line

> $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

Comment: can you try without the stateless function?